# UserRepository return null in @Autowired

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, atmosphere

I'm using atmosphere with spring boot but couldn't use Repository.

I've tried to search on google and spent 4-5 hours on that. If you know please help me. Thanks in advance

Here my code

```java
import ...

@AtmosphereHandlerService(path = "/stream",
        interceptors= {AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor.class,
                BroadcastOnPostAtmosphereInterceptor.class})
@Service
public class ServerService extends OnMessage<String> {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerService.class);
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, UserProtocol> users = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, UserProtocol>();
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, GuestProtocol> guests = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, GuestProtocol>();
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository; //always null
    @Override
    public void onMessage(AtmosphereResponse response, String message) throws IOException {
        logger.info(message);
        String uuid = response.uuid();
        logger.info(uuid);
       // UserRepository userRepository = new
        AtmosphereResource r = response.resource();
        List<User> users = userRepository.findUserById((long) 1);

//        logger.info(test.getName());
        logger.info("aa");

    }
}
```

```java
package com.a.server.repository;
import java.util.List;

import com.a.server.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findUserById(Long id);
}
```

Comment: I hope you're not running this class directly, but the spring application class.

Comment: are you missing `@EnableRepository` annotation?

Comment: @Deadpool I think it's not required if spring-data-jpa is on classpath. I never need this annotation when I use spring boot starters.

Answer (score 0):

This is my spring application class.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ServerApplication {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public EmbeddedAtmosphereInitializer atmosphereInitializer() {
        return new EmbeddedAtmosphereInitializer();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean atmosphereServlet() {
        // Dispatcher servlet is mapped to '/home' to allow the AtmosphereServlet
        // to be mapped to '/chat'
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                new AtmosphereServlet(), "/stream");
        registration.addInitParameter("org.atmosphere.cpr.packages", "sample");
        registration.addInitParameter("org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor"
                + ".clientHeartbeatFrequencyInSeconds", "10");
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(0);
        // Need to occur before the EmbeddedAtmosphereInitializer
        registration.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return registration;
    }

    @Configuration
    static class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("");
        }

    }

    private static class EmbeddedAtmosphereInitializer extends ContainerInitializer
            implements ServletContextInitializer {

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            onStartup(Collections.<Class<?>> emptySet(), servletContext);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57034494/edit) your question instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Kartik I tried but it said a lot of codes. I couldn't submit